# Java, WEBlogic error: weblogic.management.DeploymentException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException:

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, weblogic

good day
I have a serious problem, developed a maven project. And when I upload my EAR project to welogic I have an error that does not allow me, I have two environments, the local and development. The funny thing is that the development that is on the server goes up without problems but I cannot upload it to my premises to carry out the tests. The message is as follows (I've been trying to solve for a couple of weeks, please help):

```
weblogic.management.DeploymentException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NamingException: CDIExtension was previously bound from another application 'Common-ConfigurationEAR'; remaining name ''
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension.initialize(CDIExtension.java:199)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension.beforeBeanDiscovery(CDIExtension.java:300)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:267)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:263)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.invokeOnInstance(WeldMethodImpl.java:164)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.ForwardingWeldMethod.invokeOnInstance(ForwardingWeldMethod.java:51)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:154)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:245)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:233)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:213)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:75)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.BeforeBeanDiscoveryImpl.fire(BeforeBeanDiscoveryImpl.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.startInitialization(WeldBootstrap.java:335)
    at com.oracle.injection.provider.weld.WeldInjectionContainer.initialize(WeldInjectionContainer.java:92)
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIAppDeploymentExtension.initCdi(CDIAppDeploymentExtension.java:72)
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIAppDeploymentExtension.activate(CDIAppDeploymentExtension.java:49)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.AppDeploymentExtensionFlow.activate(AppDeploymentExtensionFlow.java:37)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:61)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:587)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doCommit(StartOperation.java:151)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:339)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:846)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1275)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:442)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:176)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: CDIExtension was previously bound from another application 'Common-ConfigurationEAR'; remaining name ''
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.VersionHandler.checkApp(VersionHandler.java:415)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.VersionHandler.rebindHere(VersionHandler.java:304)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.ServerNamingNode.rebindHere(ServerNamingNode.java:221)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.rebind(BasicNamingNode.java:422)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLEventContextImpl.rebind(WLEventContextImpl.java:112)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension.initialize(CDIExtension.java:196)
```

Comment: From the stack trace it looks like another application(Common-ConfigurationEAR) is using "CDIExtension". Can you share the Weblogic Version used?

Comment: the version is 12.1.3